# How to call value from string folder in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do i call a link that is stored under 
R.strings.myLink , in the below line

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.myLink.com");
```

Comment: Like this : `URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.app_name));`

Answer (score 0):

`getString(R.string.myLink)`

If above shows error, then use below:

`context.getResources().getString(R.string.myLink)`

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(getResources().getString(R.string.urllink));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```